# Whitelisting our app to prevent connection blocking?

Tags: firewalls, antivirus, whitelist

We publish a Windows desktop app, and while I've run VirusTotal on all of our files with no hits, some security software blocks incoming connections on ports we use, leading to frequent user support issues. Both our installer and the installed app are signed.

Our installer automatically adds exclusion rules to Windows Defender Firewall for the ports we use, but I'm not aware of any similar APIs provided by security software vendors (e.g. Norton, Avast, ESET, Kaspersky, McAfee, etc).

Normally, I would run VirusTotal, contact each vendor that flagged our app and apply to be whitelisted. But, *none* of them actually flag our app, yet many of them *do* block communication until we walk our users through the process of creating an exception.

Is there typically a different 'firewall whitelist' that I should be inquiring about, or do we need to make signed PowerShell scripts available for users to download, or ... ?

Comment: What do you plan to do if the user is behind a router without UPnP enabled?

Comment: The connection is between a VR headset and their PC, so it's all on the LAN side

Comment: That is the reason why so many protocols are just built on top of HTTP(S): this one passes every firewall in its default config...